# CDK deploy with 2 repositories using the same OpenID Connect provider URL in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, github-actions, openid, aws-cdk

I have 2 repositories with a Github CDK stack deploying to the same AWS account, and both repositories use the same OpenID Connect provider URL (https://token.actions.githubusercontent.com),
is it not possible as the OpenID Connect provider URL needs to be unique ?
is there any workaround ?

I tried changing the id of the provider, the id of the stack and the role, but always the same error.

```js
import { GithubActionsIdentityProvider, GithubActionsRole } from 'aws-cdk-github-oidc';
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import * as iam from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-iam';

export interface GITHUB_STACK_CONFIG {
  owner: string;
  repo: string;
  stage: string;
  policy?: iam.IManagedPolicy;
}

export class GithubStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.App, id: string, props: cdk.StackProps & GITHUB_STACK_CONFIG) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const { owner, repo, stage } = props;
    let { policy } = props;
    if (!policy) {
      policy = iam.ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName('AdministratorAccess');
    }

    const provider = new GithubActionsIdentityProvider(this, 'GithubProviderWeb');
    const deployRole = new GithubActionsRole(this, 'DeployRole2', {
      provider,
      owner,
      repo,
      filter: `ref:refs/heads/env/${stage}`,
      roleName: 'IAC-2-DeployRole',
      description: 'This role is used by Github to Deploy into this account',
      maxSessionDuration: cdk.Duration.hours(2),
    });

    deployRole.addManagedPolicy(policy);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround that in the stack I provide the two deployRoles and then I copied the same stack in my other repository, let me know if there is a better solution..

Answer (score 0):

You can only **create** the provider once per account. So only one stack should *create* the provider. All other stacks should reference the existing provider using the `fromAccount` method.

```js
// create the provider (must not exist!)
const provider = GithubActionsIdentityProvider(this, 'GithubProvider');
// use an existing provider
const provider = GithubActionsIdentityProvider.fromAccount(this, 'GithubProvider');
```

The id provided does not matter; they can be the same or different -- ids are basically only relevant *within* each stack. Different stacks can use the same ids without issue.

What you might want to do is have an independent stack for your identity providers in the account. Then all of your other various repositories can just use the `fromAccount` method.